# Rasterize Function in QGIS 2.18.13 Gives an Error

Tags: qgis, gdal-rasterize

I just updated QGIS to 2.18.13 and now I'm having trouble using the GDAL [Conversion] function, Rasterize (vector to raster).

I have sixteen vectors I made and I want to convert them to rasters. I've done this before with little to no issue, and I have never gotten the error I keep getting.

The message log says:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

but it says this before I can even open a window. Literally, I click "Rasterize (vector to raster)" and this error comes up before I can open a new window to put in the vector I want to rasterize, or the attribute that I want to fill the raster. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: i see this too...  happens from processing, but it works fine if you use the menu (Raster > Conversions > Rasterize). It seems to be a [known issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16061)

Comment: Yeah I always just use the toolbox menu now. It seems like the dropdown menu should work, though, but thanks for the pointer!